# pgfplots: legend style breaks \ref for legend to name

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am encountering the situation, where the `legend to name` with `\ref` seems to fail whenever I have set a global legend style.

Please see

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.tikz}
\tikz{\begin{axis}[
        width=2cm,height=4cm,
        ]
        \addplot +[]%
        table[row sep=crcr] {%
            1 1\\
            2 4\\
        };
        \label{testAAA}
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend to name={\legendname},
        width=2cm,height=4cm,
        ]
        %
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle={testAAA}}\addlegendentry{AAA}%
        \addplot +[]%
        table[row sep=crcr] {%
            1 2\\
            5 10\\
        };
        \addlegendentry{BBB}%
\end{axis}}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable,tikzscale,subcaption}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={%
        legend style = {%
            at={(axis description cs:0.5,1.1)},% <-- this causes troubles with \ref 
        },%
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \newcommand{\legendname}{testlegend}%
        \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics{test.tikz}}\\
        \ref{testlegend}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives me

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \pgfplots@evalute@tikz@coord@system@interface@axis@description ...
>                                                     {#1}{#2} l.59       \ref{testlegend}

I am using lualatex with texlive 2018.

However, when removing the `pgfplotsset` command, it seems to work fine.

What I am doing wrong here?

I know that in the case I'm using `legned to name`, the legend positions does not make sense. However, I have a longer document, where I am using `legend to name` only for some figures. For the others, I want to the use the default settings set via the above mentioned command.

Comment: `\includegraphics` cannot be used to include some TeX code.

Comment: If you replace `\includegraphics` by the correct syntax `\input` and omit the `axis description cs:`, about which the pgfplots manual says on p. 239 "In most cases, it is not necessary to explicitly write axis description cs as it is the default coordinate system for any axis description.", then the code works fine. Frankly, I do not see any reason for that. With legend to name you anyway store the legend such that you can reuse it with `\ref`, so what is the position good for?

Comment: @marmot thanks for your reply, its the `\includegraphics` overloaded by `tikzscale` which is designed to handle tikz pictures.

Comment: @marmot as mentioned in the last paragraph, I have also many other figures where I want to apply the default rules to which do not use `legend to name`

Comment: @marmot thanks for the hint that its working when removing `axis description cs`! I didn't know that its the default. But doesn't it seem to be bug in pgf/pgfplots then?

Comment: I am not sure I would call it a bug. You really do not place the legend anywhere in you plot, but just later. I guess that, if you were to place the legend in the plot, the issue would not arise. (I do not understand your `\includegraphics` statement either. `\includegraphics` expects the argument to be a, say, pdf graphics, not a TeX code. And what is `tikzscale`? I guess you need to describe in more detail what you want to achieve.)